# Recursion in FOR loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm using recursion in for loop:

```
var matrix = [
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
];
var startVertex = 1;
var vertices = [];
var lastTakenOff = -1;

var findHamilton = function (v) {
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix[v].length; i++) {
    if (matrix[v][i] === 1 && vertices.indexOf(i) === -1 && i > lastTakenOff &&
        vertices.length < matrix[v].length) {
      vertices.push(i);
      console.log(vertices)
      lastTakenOff = -1;
      return findHamilton(i);
    } else if (vertices.length < matrix[v].length) {
      console.log(vertices);
      lastTakenOff = vertices.pop();
      return findHamilton(vertices[vertices.length - 1]);
    }
  }
};

vertices.push(startVertex);
findHamilton(startVertex);
console.log(vertices)
```

After 3 iteration I got error: matrix[v] is undefined in for loop. if I haven't "else if" everything is ok. How can I use recursion in if else?

Edit:
I added all my code

Comment: You haven't shown what `matrix` is or what it contains. That is probably the source of your problems.

Comment: Recursion requires a base case, and a function call to itself. If / Else is almost always used to determine whether to return a value or a call to the function.

Comment: Andrue is right, if /else is a problem. Could you give me more hint how to fix it?

Comment: Please post all code, where is `matrix` defined and `vertices` we can't help you if you don't post the entire code

Comment: what is vertices value going into this function?

Comment: Huge issues here : You're using both parameters (v), local scoped vars (i), and global vars (startVertex, vertices, lastTakenOff). Names are poorly choosen. Conditionals are too long. To debug, your console.log will not work since the array will be modified before you watch its content (use `console.log(vertices.slice(0))`... ...  Your code is a nightmare by design, make things clean and bugs will disappear.

Comment: @Michal Ok you need take a look at `matrix[v].length` if v position doesn't exist, matrix[v] will be `undefined` I recommend you validate first if `v < matrix.length` another piece of advice is if you want to use recursion I think you must clean the code as well as you be able to evaluate your code by sustitution model I mean in your mind, try to avoid `for loops` if you can.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
    startVertex = 1;
```

to this:

```
    startVertex = 0;
```

I think you're starting off on the array at position 1 but it's actually 4 deep starting at 0. By starting at 1 you are getting to the end of the array count sooner than the length of the array.

see if that works

Comment: or switch around the [0] and the [v] depending on what your looking to get

Comment: wait, why are you starting with startVertex = 1? Shouldn't that be startVertex = 0?

Comment: No, its doesn't matter it is `1` or `0`. In this example of matrix, I can use `startVertex` from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem or one of them is this sentence `return findHamilton(vertices[vertices.length - 1]);` findHamilton is waiting for a int argument but `vertices[vertices.length - 1]` could be a  `undefined`
So I don't know is this will return the values waited by you but try this:

```
var matrix = [
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
];
var startVertex = 1;
var vertices = [];
var lastTakenOff = -1;

var findHamilton = function (v) {

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix[v].length; i++) {

        if (matrix[v][i] === 1 && vertices.indexOf(i) === -1 && i > lastTakenOff &&
            vertices.length < matrix[v].length) {
            vertices.push(i);
            console.log(vertices)
            lastTakenOff = -1;
            return findHamilton(i);
        } else if (vertices[vertices.length - 1] && v < matrix.length && vertices.length < matrix[v].length) {
            console.log(vertices);
            lastTakenOff = vertices.pop();
            return findHamilton(vertices[vertices.length - 1]);          
        }
    }
};


vertices.push(startVertex);
findHamilton(startVertex);
console.log(vertices)
```

I just edited the `else if` predicate

Comment: In this startVertex and this matrix `else if` should not be executed. In some way it is and I want to know how to fix. For example if you remove all `else if` and you will have only `if` then everything is ok. This 'else if' is necessary if `startVertex = 2`.